# Asp.net MVC web api Response.CreateResponse sending odd content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, base64, httpresponse

Am currently communicating to a Mobile device using Windows Compact Framework 3.5. The message sent to the device is built is as thus,

```
HttpResponseMessage result;
var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"windows-1252\"?><message type=\"response\"><header><datetime>2013-04-03T09:49:35</datetime><sender version=\"1.1.4.1138\"><userid>Connect Server</userid></sender><commandlist><module>ADMIN</module><command1>VALIDATE</command1></commandlist><result type=\"ok\"/></header></message>");

result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
```

The device then retrieves the message and then uses

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseContent);
```

After decoding the message is:

```
&lt;base64Binary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"&gt;PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0id2luZG93cy0xMjUyIj8+PG1lc3NhZ2UgdHlwZT0icmVzcG9uc2UiPjxoZWFkZXI+PGRhdGV0aW1lPjIwMTMtMDQtMDNUMDk6NDk6MzU8L2RhdGV0aW1lPjxzZW5kZXIgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4xLjQuMTEzOCI+PHVzZXJpZD5Db25uZWN0IFNlcnZlcjwvdXNlcmlkPjwvc2VuZGVyPjxjb21tYW5kbGlzdD48bW9kdWxlPkFETUlOPC9tb2R1bGU+PGNvbW1hbmQxPlZBTElEQVRFPC9jb21tYW5kMT48L2NvbW1hbmRsaXN0PjxyZXN1bHQgdHlwZT0ib2siLz48L2hlYWRlcj48L21lc3NhZ2U+&lt;/base64Binary&gt;
```

Tried decoding the message on the server before sending it off and it's fine. Unsure what could be going wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request.CreateResponse() uses ObjectContent.  For this scenario, you don't want that. You should use either StringContent or StreamContent to return the XML.  See this question for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/15372410/6819

Answer (score 0):

You are encoding your XML as binary. You are then returning a byte array. Then your client requests XML in the `Accept: application/xml` header. The Web API serializes the binary into XML. That's what you're seeing.

Just return the XML as a string and you should have no problems, unless you've tried that already?

[See here for similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662028/webapi-to-return-xml).

Comment: That will have the same problem because Request.CreateResponse uses ObjectContent which assumes you want to use an object serializer.  Returning a string will get an XML serialization of a string object, complete with seralization namespaces.

Comment: @DarrelMiller I expect you're right. That makes the accepted answer on the question I linked to wrong or misleading.

Comment: The wierd thing about the question you linked to is that the OP is using StringContent, so that should return just fine.  The only problem is StringContent sets the content-type to text/plain so that needs to be overridden.  But yes, the accepted answer is misleading.